# Error in converting string to datetime in C#.net

Tags: c#-4.0, datetime, date-format

I am getting an error in converting string to date in C#. 
The error is:
`string is not valid datetime.`
Below is the code that I am using to convert string into datetime.

```
string[] DateFormat = { "dd-MM-yyyy", "dd/MM/yyyy", "MM-dd-yyyy", "MM/dd/yyyy" ,"dd-MMM-yy"};
            VendorSinceDate = DateTime.ParseExact(dtresult.Rows[0]["VendorSinceDate"].ToString(),DateFormat,System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None);

//dtresult.Rows[0]["VendorSinceDate"].ToString()="06-Jun-12 12:00:00 AM";
```

Comment: Short from inviting Bobble Tables, there's probably no bigger mistake you can make than storing dates in a table column of type text.  Fix the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of your possible DateFormats include the time, but the string you're trying to convert does.

You need to add a matching DateFormat, e.g. `dd-MMM-yy hh:mm:ss tt`